# GIT: How to checkout a file from a previous commit without overwriting the current one?

Tags: git, version-control

Several commits previously I had some javascript working one way. Over the course of several commits I now have it working another way. I would like to look at the file as it was several commits ago because I might want to use aspects of it in the new javascript. However I don't want to revert my current file to exactly what it was. I just want to literally open the old file, have a look around it and maybe copy and paste some code from it into the new file.

How do I retrieve a copy of the file from a previous commit without overwriting the most recent version?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Simply redirect the output of `git show` to a file.

```
git show *SHA-of-old-commit*:*filename* > newfilename
```

eg:

```
git show 7c4eacc:main.cpp > main.cpp.old
```

Comment: when I do this I get an error like: `fatal: Path 'main.cpp' exists on disk, but not in '7c4eacc'`. Any idea why?

Comment: @JPLew You have to use the SHA value of the particular commit. Here 7c4eacc was only an example.

Comment: i figured it out, thanks. The problem was that file didn't exist in that particular commit\