# retrieve snippets in old commit git

Tags: git

Several commits ago, I deleted/modified some lines in a python script. I now want to retrieve part or all of those lines and incorporate them into the latest version, but most of that old version I do not want to revert to. I could do

```
git checkout <old-commit>
cp my_script.py my_script1.py
git checkout master
vim my_script.py my_script1.py 
<make changes>
rm my_script1.py
```

Is there a better way than this?

Related question: I find myself in this situation reasonably often, is this a sign I could organize the repo better?

Comment: You can check out a single file using `git checkout <commit> my_script.py`.

Comment: @dan1st This overwrites the current `my_script.py`

Comment: `git show <old-commit>:my_script.py > my_script1.py` See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12528611/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+retrieve+file+from+old+commit

Comment: This is a good trick. Maybe sometimes it would be the best way to solve my problem but more patch often I'd say patch mode (in the accepted answer) would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I now want to retrieve [some deleted lines] lines [of a particular file]

Besides [phd's suggestion in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67589146/retrieve-snippets-in-old-commit-git#comment119467479_67589146) that links to [GIT: How to checkout a file from a previous commit without overwriting the current one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12527964/1256452), note that you can also use the patch mode of `git restore` (or single-file `git checkout`):

```
git restore -p --source=<commit> -- my_script.py
```

or:

```
git checkout -p <commit> -- my_script.py
```

The double dash `--` here is not *required* but is a good habit to get into, as it helps avoid problems when you have a file named `master` or a branch named `script.py`.  The stuff on the left side of the `--` is *not* a file name, and the stuff on the right of the `--` *is* a file name, even if something on whichever side seems to resemble a thing that it isn't.

(I personally dislike the patch mode, but for some very special cases, it's ideal.  `git restore` is new in Git 2.23: it mostly does things you could do with the old complicated variants of `git checkout`, which all still work.)

Since the lines are deleted, `git blame` does not help, but `git blame --reverse` can; that's another tool to keep handy in your workshop.

Comment: Great, patch mode is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks also for the tips about "git restore" and "--".